# beamer - Theorem - Extra (descriptive) text after (......)

Tags: beamer, theorems

I want to put some extra text (green color text in the picture) after the
`Theorem (...)`, NOT inside the parenthesis, but still at the same (top) line.

How to set the options to achieve this? Please.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{theorem}[ABC formula {\color{green} Compute ABC}]
  $ABC = abc$.
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what template `theorem begin` exists for. The default is

> ```
> \defbeamertemplate*{theorem begin}{default}
> {%
>   \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
>   {%
>     \inserttheoremname
>     \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
>   }%
> }
> ```

And what you need is

```
\defbeamertemplate*{theorem begin}{no ()}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {%
    \inserttheoremname
    \ \inserttheoremaddition%
  }%
}
```

## Complete code

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}
\defbeamertemplate*{theorem begin}{no ()}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {%
    \inserttheoremname
    \ \inserttheoremaddition%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{theorem}[(ABC formula) \color{green} Compute ABC]
            $ABC = abc$.
        \end{theorem}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```